# How to count the number of instances within a table (Countifs)

Tags: sql, count

Thank you so much for looking!

Here is [a link to the tables](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xutikxgajphx1ua/Table.xlsx?dl=0).

Normally this table would have a Field in Check Call name that is "Pickup - Actual" signalling that this has been picked up. However in certain circumstances the CheckCallName will bypass the pickup and move to delivered status. In cases like this I want to pull the query to treat the "Delivered" status in the same manner that Pickup Actual was being used.

So where kpo.loadtracking does not have Pickup - Actual in the Check Call Name field for any one order, I want to pull the date (KeypointStatusDate) the status changed to 'Delivered'.

I figured this would be something like  "where the status count of Pickup-Actual is greater than 0 then pull the  earliest status update date for pickup actual.

However when the count is = 0, I'd want it to pull the date relevant to the Delivered CheckCallName.

Table 1 should Pull 10/5 - 
Table 2 should Pull 10/2

My current code is below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Load.LoadNumber             
    ,CustomerName               
    ,OrderStatus                
    ,PickedUpOn             
    ,CheckCallName              
    ,Min(LoadTracking.KeypointStatusDate) AS Earliest_Check_Call                
    ,CustomerRate               
    ,CarrierCost                
    ,Miles                          
FROM kpo.load               
INNER JOIN kpo.LoadExtension ON LOAD.LoadId = LoadExtension.LoadId              
INNER JOIN kpo.Customer ON customer.CustomerId = LOAD.CustomerID                
INNER JOIN kpo.LoadTracking ON LoadTracking.LoadId = LOAD.LoadId                    
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(MONTH, GETDATE(), LoadTracking.KeypointStatusDate) = - 2
    AND OrderStatus <> 'VOID'
    AND CheckCallName = 'Pickup - Actual'

--- WE NEED TO THEN LOOK AT EACH LOAD 
--- AND IF THERE IS NO PICKUP-ACTUAL THEN IT PULLS IN THE DELIVERED DATE.
--- THERE ARE SOME ORDERS THAT GO STRAIGHT TO DELIVERED STATUS. (453653)

GROUP BY                
    Load.LoadNumber
    ,OrderStatus                
    ,CustomerName               
    ,CheckCallName              
    ,PickedUpOn             
    ,CustomerRate               
    ,CarrierCost                
    ,Miles
ORDER BY
    Earliest_Check_Call
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query uses non-standard functions). Please add the tag for the database product you are using

Comment: Yeah, you haven't made this question very accessible.  I've spent probably 15 minutes looking at it and don't yet know for sure what you are asking.  Additionally, your pull results in table "comments" don't match results show above and I have no idea what the "10/" means.  I have all kinds of questions, though even if they are all answered I'm not sure I'll have all the information needed.  Still, some thoughts: 1. fix the process so status isn't skipped, 2. add a column indicating if you processed it or not, 3. if you cannot change this table, create a new table to hold that new column